# Can't run C++ clr dll from C# - Dll Unloaded?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I've seen several people with a similar problem, but so far none of those fixes has worked.

I've got a C# application (Windows forms) and /I'm trying to use a C++ clr dll.  The dll seems to load fine, I can build and run the application, however if I call into the dll the program throws a FileNotFound exception "Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.":"MyLibrary.dll".

The last error is 1008, Error_No_Token

The dll is in the folder with the exe.

I've been examining things with peverify and ildasm, but haven't found any issues there.

I ran dependency walker on it and saw this unusual sequence in the logs:

Unloaded "MYLIBRARY.DLL" at address 0x00007FFB93400000.

LoadLibraryExW("C:\source\tools\ToolItemProj\ToolItem\ToolItem\bin\x64\Debug\MyLibrary.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).

I've run ProcMon on it and come up with several entires, most of them succeed, but QueryAllInformation has a BufferOverflow error and CreateFileMapping failed (once) with FileLockedWithOnlyReaders (It then ran again and Succeeded).  Creating an INI also seemed to fail with NameNotFound.

So it looks like it's unloading the dll at runtime because of a buffer overflow.  But, how do I trace it?  Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Usually "The specified module could not be found" suggests some dlls are missing. Were your vcredist's(x64) properly installed? Does the C++ dll depends on anything that you might forget to put under your assembly directory or search path? Also, is the C++ dll compiled in x64?

Answer (score -1):

This has been solved.  The dll includes another dll which I didn't have.  I was able to track this dll through the original developer.

Comment: For such cases the "Dependency Walker" tool is invaluable.  It comes with many versions of the Windows SDK (formerly Platform SDK) and is also available separately at http://www.dependencywalker.com  You said you already ran it... I would suggest not just looking at the log but also at the static analysis it performs when you open a DLL.  It will read the list of imports and tell you which DLLs are needed but not found, as well as showing you version information for the ones that are found (in case a version mismatch is your problem).